# Difference between an API and SDK

Tags: sdk, terminology

I am trying to explain to a non-developer the difference between an API an SDK. I need to explain why a commercial fingerprint software vendor will likely not provide an SDK, although they may certainly have used one.

Both device vendors and software vendors can and should expose a well-defined API. This API allows other software programs to (be written to) inter-operate with the vendor’s own software components or hardware devices.

If someone has more ideas to explain this clearly, I would very much appreciate the suggestions. I want to emphasize that **the goal is to explain the concepts to a non-programmer who does not know developer lingo**.

Specifically, in the context of a fingerprint sensor versus software to do enrollment/verification, here is how I attempted to explain it:

> If I am a fingerprint device/sensor manufacturer and not in the
>   business of writing software, the ways I could better market my
>   product are:
>
> 1. Make sure my device drivers are installable on a wide variety of operating systems
> 2. Define and provide an API for software developers to write programs (e.g., for enrollment, verification) to “talk” to or use my
>      device
> 3. Develop and provide an SDK (one step beyond an API) to make it easier and faster for software developers to write programs that work
>      with my device. SDKs may provide helper code libraries, reference
>      applications, documentation etc.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Piece of cake:

- an API is an **interface**. It's like the specification of the telephone system or the electrical wiring in your house. Anything* can use it as long as it knows how to interface. You can even buy off-the-shelf software to use a particular API, just as you can buy off the shelf telephone equipment or devices that plug into the AC wiring in your house.
- an SDK is **implementation tooling**. It's like a kit that allows** you to build something custom to hook up to the telephone system or electrical wiring.

*Anything can use an API. Some APIs have security provisions to require license keys, authentication, etc. which may prohibit complete use of the API in particular instances, but that's only because particular authentication/authorization steps fail. Any software that presents the right credentials (if required) can use the API.

**Technically, if an API is well-documented, you don't need an SDK to build your own software to use the API. But having an SDK generally makes the process much easier.

Comment: Some other ideas I have for explaining this is the iPhone example (proprietary code but well-defined API), telephone jack or USB port example to explain what a software interface is with an easier to visually understand hardware analogy

Comment: Continuing this good explanation, i.e. an API could be for example a http/REST API, while the SDK could be a library on top of HttpClient to make it faster and easier to interact with the REST web services.

Comment: More simply, an API is an interface. Whereas an SDK is an abstraction layer over the interface.

Comment: SDK isn't necessarily an abstraction layer over the interface; SDK is an implementation of the interface. (if there's another abstraction layer, the question is why it isn't specified as part of the interface itself)

Comment: I agree with this definition, but at the same time wonder why iOS and Android use the term API for e.g. the Bluetooth library (iOS Core Bluetooth API, Android Bluetooth APIs)?

Answer (score 63):

**API** is like the building blocks of some puzzling game that a child plays with to join blocks in different shapes and build something they can think of.

**SDK**, on the other hand, is a proper workshop where all of the development tools are available, rather than pre-shaped building blocks. In a workshop you have the actual tools and you are not limited to blocks, and can therefore make your own blocks, or can create something without any blocks to begin with.

***coding without an SDK or API*** is like making everything from scratch without a workshop - you have to even make your own tools

Comment: You say SDK has no pre-shaped building blocks but JAVA SDK comes with Data Structures such as ArrayList or HashMap... ?

Comment: Yes, You can consider it as building block but On the other hand Java Provides it as a tool not as a building block.

Comment: I came across this question when I was trying to read and understand facebook documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript
One thing confuses me is that facebook calls it a javascript SDK, which in my opinion is more like an API. Because it doesn't provide any tangible tools but only a library which developers can use, Shouldn't this be called API instead of SDK?

Comment: SDK explanation doesn't quite work imo. Rather than `not limited to blocks, or can create something without any blocks to begin with`, more like the SDK gives you even better compositions of the API's blocks to work with. SDK builds on top of an API.

Answer (score 28):

Suppose company C offers product P and P involves software in some way. Then C can offer a library/set of libraries to software developers that drive P's software systems.

That library/libraries are an **SDK**. It is part of the systems of P. It is a kit for software developers to use in order to modify, configure, fix, improve, etc the software piece of P.

If C wants to offer P's functionality to other companies/systems, it does so with an **API**.

This is an interface to P. A way for external systems to interact with P.

If you think in terms of implementation, they will seem quite similar. Especially now that the internet has become like one large distributed operating system.

In purpose, though, they are actually quite distinct.

You build something with an SDK and you use or consume something with an API.

Comment: You should just edit your answer down to the last line and skip all the blah-de-blah.

Comment: If C offers a set of libraries that drive P''s software, those libraries make up the API(s), not an SDK (unless it's an absolutely minimal SDK that is nothing but the API).  The SDK would include these API's plus all the goodies that developers need other than a raw API, hence the "kit".  So you're right about building something vs. using/consuming(+/controlling/interacting), but the distinction is otherwise muddled.

Answer (score 14):

**Application Programming Interface** is a set of routines/data structures/classes which specifies a way to interact with the target platform/software like OS X, Android, project management application, virtualization software etc.

While **Software Development Kit** is a wrapper around API/s that makes the job easy for developers.

For example, Android SDK facilitates developers to interact with the Android platform as a whole while the platform itself is built by composite software components communicating via APIs.

Also, sometimes SDKs are built to facilitate development in a specific programming language. For example, [Selenium web driver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) (built in Java) provides APIs to drive any browser natively, while [capybara](https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara) can be considered an an SDK that facilitates Ruby developers to use Selenium web driver. However, Selenium web driver is also an SDK by itself as it combines interaction with various native browser drivers into one package.

Comment: Just thought that it will be nice to quote some examples.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure there's any official definition of these two terms.  I understand an API to be a set of documented programmable libraries and supporting source such as headers or IDL files.  SDKs usually contain APIs but often often add compilers, tools, and samples to the mix.

Comment: technically APIs need to be specified but don't have to be publicly documented, they could be secret.

Answer (score 8):

API is specifications on how to do something, an interface, such as "The railroad tracks are four feet apart, and the metal bar is 1 inch wide" Now that you have the API you can now build a train that will fit on those railroad tracks if you want to go anywhere. API is just information on how to build your code, it doesn't do anything.

SDK is some package of actual tools that already worried about the specifications. "Here's a train, some coal, and a maintenance man. Use it to go from place to place" With the SDK you don't worry about specifics. An SDK is actual code, it can be used by itself to do something, but of course, the train won't start up spontaneously, you still have to get a conductor to control the train.

SDKs also have their own APIs. "If you want to power the train put coal in it", "Pull the blue lever to move the train.", "If the train starts acting funny, call the maintenance man" etc.

Answer (score 5):

API = Dictionary of available words and their meanings (and the required grammar to combine them)

SDK = A Word processing system… for 2 year old babies… that writes right from ideas

Although you COULD go to school and become a master in your language after a few years, using the SDK will help you write whole meaningful sentences in no time (Forgiving the fact that, in this example, as a baby you haven't even gotten to learn any other language for at least to learn to use the SDK.)

Answer (score 2):

How about... It's like if you wanted to install a home theatre system in your house. Using an API is like getting all the wires, screws, bits, and pieces. The possibilities are endless (constrained only by the pieces you receive), but sometimes overwhelming. An SDK is like getting a kit. You still have to put it together, but it's more like getting pre-cut pieces and instructions for an IKEA bookshelf than a box of screws.

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://docs.outmatchapi.com/blog/2022/12/01/are-api-sdks-important#sdk-software-development-kit)

> An API (Application Programming Interface) is a set of rules
> specifying how two software programs should interact with each other.
> It provides a way for different software systems to communicate with
> each other and exchange data and information.
>
> An SDK (Software Development Kit) is a set of tools and libraries that
> provides developers with the ability to build applications for a
> certain software or platform. It typically includes an API,
> documentation, and sample code, and may also include tools and
> libraries for testing and debugging.
>
> In general, an API is a way for different software systems to
> communicate with each other, while an SDK is a set of tools and
> libraries that help a developer build applications for a specific
> platform.