# What's the difference between the Google API and the Google SDK?

Tags: google-drive-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference of ‘Drive SDK’ and ‘Drive API’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687443/difference-of-drive-sdk-and-drive-api)

I'm trying to work with linking Google Drive accounts to an account registered through my website and I'm having some trouble understanding what the difference is between the Google Drive API and the Google SDK (which contains the Drive functionality as well as other Google service within).  I don't feel that the differences have been much (or at all) discussed in the documentation because it might be somewhat of "common sense" for those who are used to working on web applications.  For those like myself who are not accustomed to this kind of programming, I have a hard time grasping when I should use the Drive API and when I should use the downloadable SDK.

What I'm trying to do on my website is essentially give a user the ability to create an account on my site and then go and link all their Google accounts to their account.  The problem is that I see the SDK doesn't natively allow for multiple access tokens.  With that said, I feel I'm a little stuck in the dark here and am having to sort of "invent my own method" to get around this.  Can anyone perhaps clear the air and explain what the fundamental differences are between the two and perhaps provide examples of when I should use one or the other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687443/difference-of-drive-sdk-and-drive-api?rq=1

Comment: Ravi, thanks for the link... I've voted to close my question!