# How to Build an SDK for my application?

Tags: java, eclipse, sdk

I am coding a JAVA project and I want to create an SDK to be used with Eclipse. How could I build one?

My project is actually a backbone of 20+ functions. I want to provide and SDK for the developers to develop above this backbone, just like how developers use ANDROID SDK. So how can I make an SDK?

Comment: What do you mean by "an SDK"?

Comment: More Details added. Please ask for more, if needed?. Thanks @immibis

Comment: So basically you want other people to be able to use your functions?

Comment: Yes..:). But I would prefer SDK over providing an API

Comment: What's the difference between an SDK and an API? But anyway, I would just give them the jar file with your code. An SDK is just "all the stuff you need to work with our program/OS/device/whatever" which in this case could be a single jar file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834763/api-vs-sdk

Answer (score 2):

You can create jar for your collection of classes and From eclipse you can import Jar.

So by doing this you can import classes which are in jar.

[Click Here To know how to create JAR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)