# Difference between API Level and SDK Version

Tags: android

I'm new to Android App Development.Please help me understand the difference b/w API Level and SDK Verion.
And it is not the duplicate of **Android: API level VS. *Android version*** already asked [Android: API level VS. Android version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629687/android-api-level-vs-android-version) if Android Version is not the same as SDK Version.

Comment: Is this a duplicate question because API level and SDK version are the same thing?  If so you should state that, since it is not stated in the other question.

Comment: This does seem to be a different question than the one already asked. Wouldn't this link more appropriately answer the OP's question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834763/difference-between-an-api-and-sdk